# Django-How to combine two object set & remove the common objects in these two sets

Tags: python, django, filter

i am now trying to implement a search function in django and is using the filter functions. After looking through the functions ,I couldn't find the particular function how I am going to combing two different object sets and remove the common objects in the two sets.

```
set1= book.objects.filter(name='Python')
set2= book.objects.filter(author_name='Mona')
```

Is there any function can be called to do so?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this using `exclude()` for objects in other set.

```
set1= book.objects.filter(name='Python')
set2= book.objects.filter(author_name='Mona')
non_common = set1.exclude(id__in=[o.id for o in set2])
```

Comment: yea, thanks.but how can to get the combination set of id in these two sets while  removing the common id in the two sets??